# How to call event Analytics DialogFlow by nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api, dialogflow-es

I'm using dialogflow v2 using npm https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow. 
Then I have a task to call API to get the number of messages in analytics.
https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/#/agent//analytics 
use this API
https://api.dialogflow.com/api/interactions/analytics/messages?timeInterval=1.
So anyone can suggest to me how to call that API in dialogflow npm. I can not get

- x-goog-access-token
- x-goog-id-token

Comment: is [Dialog flow analytics](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/analytics) the same as [google analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/)?  If not please remove the Google analytics tag.

Comment: The Dialogflow belongs to Google, so I think it should have google analytics tag

Comment: Google drive also belongs to google but its a completely different system and total unrelated.

Comment: I agree with you @DaImTo, so do you think https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow this package support call API analytics. Because really hard to get access token and jwt

Comment: Where did you find that API, and do you have any documentation about it? That isn't the API endpoint listed at https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2-overview

Comment: I just access to the page https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/#/agent//analytics and opened the chrome debugger tool :3 @Prisoner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2 for more about generating the auth token for a REST request using a service account. But that isn't the problem.

The real issue is that you're trying to access an internal API, and your project likely isn't permitted to this API.

The library itself doesn't have access to that portion of the API as well, so even if you were permitted (and, I should emphasize, you're probably not), you would need to make the REST calls directly without a library.